# Disabled element by given id - typescript angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, disabled-input

I need yours help. It is possible when a have list of comments as textareas and i would like to disabled single element (comment) by given this element id.
Whati have:

```
<div style="float: right">
    <button mat-button color="primary">
        <mat-icon class="md-24" (click)="edit()" >edit</mat-icon>
    </button>
     <textarea [disabled]='enableTextarea' class="comment-textarea" matInput cdkTextareaAutosize rows="2">{{comment.content}}</textarea>       
</div>
```

{{coment.content}} - is content of the comment and it is it what i want to edit (it means enable)

```
export class CommentComponent implements OnInit {

enableTextarea = true;

edit() {
    this.enableTextarea = !this.enableTextarea;
  }

}
```

Here i have two coments with id 1 and 2, and what he wants to achieve to be able to after click edit (pencil on right) disable single comments. In my code all comments are edited, no matter who clicks.

Comment: If you want to disable only one of n elements, each element needs its own variable to control the state

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demonstrating your issue?

Comment: @mwilson It's a straight forward issue.  They are driving the disabled state of all elements off of a component level variable, `enableTextarea`, that is not unique to each element.  They want uniqueness.  So they can't make them all use that one variable

Comment: Actually, could you show the code that makes your loop over all the contents? The one containing the `*ngFor` in all likelihood.

Comment: From your code I can conclude that you are not looping over data. Since you initialise only one single component, the fact that this property seems to be 'shared' is exactly that: the same boolean holds the same value, because its the same object. There is no `*ngFor` anywhere, which would _loop over an array of comments_ to display, given each of them that boolean value. I can't say it easier than that. @Taplar Probably hit the nail on the head better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `enableTextarea` from `boolean` to `boolean[]`. That way each item will be independent of the other

In your component

```typescript
enableTextarea = [false];

edit(i) {
  this.enableTextarea[i] = !this.enableTextarea[i];
}
```

Now in your html,

1. Change the loop by adding index

```html
    <div *ngFor="let comment of comments; let i = index">

       <!-- Other Contents Here -->
    </div>
```

2. change all `enableTextarea` to `enableTextarea[i]`
3. Change `edit()` to `edit(i)`

```html
                <div *ngFor="let comment of comments; let i = index">
                    <div>
                        {{comment.createDate }}
                        <div style="float: right">
                            <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="deleteComment(comment.id)">
                <mat-icon class="md-24">delete</mat-icon>
              </button>
                            <button mat-button color="primary">
                <mat-icon class="md-24" (click)="edit(i)">edit</mat-icon>
              </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="enableTextarea[i] == false">
                        <h5 class="h5-edited">editing</h5>
                    </div>
                    <textarea [disabled]='enableTextarea[i]' class="comment-textarea" matInput cdkTextareaAutosize
                    rows="2">{{comment.content}}</textarea>
                    <button mat-button color="primary" *ngIf="enableTextarea[i] == false" (click)="updateComment(comment.id)">Save
          </button>
                    <br><br><br>
        </div>
```

[See Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sktbo8?)